# How to create new unpublished page on form submit?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create custom form. On submit new page(CPT template) should be created, filled with data from form and be unpublished.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a post type page or an actual page on wordpress? Need a bit more details. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: It is custom post type with ACF PRO elements. It displays data about companies. Basically i dont want to fill the template eahtime. I want to create the form, send it to customer and let customer to upload all needed information. So in the end i will need just review and change post status from draft to published.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ACF Pro? They have this acf_form() function that creates a form that can edit or submit posts. Here's the link if you want more information https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/ :)